# Item in array is suddenly not existing

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm dynamically loading files in by finding all .rb files in a sub directory and then iterating through to load them all in. Two files must be loaded in a specific order.

1.`info.rb` must be loaded in first

2.`main.rb` must be loaded in last

Here's my code

```
TO_MOVE = %w(main info)
Dir.chdir(File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))){
  file_list = Dir.glob('**/*.rb') - IGNORE_LIST
  file_list.each_with_index { |p,pi| puts "#{pi}:#{p}" }
  puts '-----------'
  file_list.each_with_index do |path,pi|
  puts "#{pi}:#{file_list[pi]}"
    if TO_MOVE.include?(file = File.basename(path, ".rb"))
      ordered_files[file.to_sym] = file_list.delete_at(pi)
    end
  end
}
```

Here's the problem, where I'm printing the `file_list` array it prints out like so:

```
0:gem_name/data/data.rb
1:gem_name/helpers/helpers.rb
2:gem_named/info.rb
3:gem_name/main.rb
4:gem_name/routing/actions.rb
5:gem_name/routing/api.rb
```

Exactly as I'm expecting, but when it prints out the second time it prints out like this:

```
0:gem_name/data/data.rb
1:gem_name/helpers/helpers.rb
2:gem_name/info.rb
3:gem_name/routing/actions.rb
4:gem_name/routing/api.rb
```

Where is main.rb? why does it suddenly cease to exists?

Because of this it's skipping main and since it does that, main doesn't get found and moved to the end of the list I was doing

```
ordered_files[:main] = file_list.delete_at(4)
```

But that stopped working when main wasn't being loaded at index 4, I need something better then a patch job.

Why is main.rb being skipped over? I'm genuinely baffled by this. I know it exists because it errors trying to load `main.rb` because the modules that should be loaded before aren't being loaded and so there modules don't exist (which is why it errors), this is why `main.rb` is needing to be loaded in at the end.

In case you want to know the code that places the ordered files is like this:

```
file_list.unshift(ordered_files[:info]) << ordered_files[:main]
```

Comment: What is in `IGNORE_LIST`?

Comment: just some files I don't want to load up but the're all in the same dir as the file that does the loading so aren't what's affecting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you delete items from the list as you iterate over it:

```
ordered_files[file.to_sym] = file_list.delete_at(pi)
```

Here is an example of what happens:

```
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr.each_with_index do |n, i|
  puts "#{n}, #{i}"
  arr.delete_at(i) if i == 2
end
```

will output:

```
0, 0
1, 1
2, 2
4, 3
5, 4
```

If you want to delete all files you add to `ordered_files` I think using [`reject!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-reject-21) will work better:

```
file_list.reject! do |path|
  puts "#{path]}"
  if TO_MOVE.include?(file = File.basename(path, ".rb"))
    ordered_files[file.to_sym] = path
  end
end
```

This tells the `file_list` to remove each item for which the block returns a truthy value (anything but `false` or `nil`), which will be the case for all the files you add to `ordered_files`.

Comment: Whilst I will probably give that a try I don't think what you suggested as the problem is the issue, for one thing it prints out the current item it's look at before it does anything with it so it should still display, secondly if I add `puts "moving #{file} at index #{pi}"` into the if statement it only prints out `puts "moving #{file} at index #{pi}"` and nothing else, so it only moves one file so it can't be because I'm deleting it.

Comment: @user3536548 - it skips `main` since you deleted `info` before the loop read it. Before the delete `main` is in index `3`, but after you delete `info`, `main` is now in index `2`. The next loop, the iteration looks at the item at index `3`, which is now `actions`, so `main` is skipped.

Comment: Your right, I just realised it was doing that. after doing `puts file_list[3]` it goes from main.rb to actions.rb so it skips over main.rb before it gets to it and thus it never gets moved.

Comment: Ok, just tried it and it worked. You might want to edit your answer at the end, the put's  string concat has a `]` in it that breaks the code, easily fixed though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this:

```
if TO_MOVE.include?(file = File.basename(path, ".rb"))
```

It results in code that is confusing to anyone having to maintain the code later, including your future self.

Instead, do:

```
file = File.basename(path, ".rb") 
if TO_MOVE.include?(file)
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot double brackets, thanks for reminding me.